# Create an application from Model jar and viewcontroller jar

Tags: oracle-adf

I have Model project jar and ViewController Project jar of the same application but I don't have the original application.

I tried creating a new Fusion Web application and added the model jar as dependency in Model Project of the new application and ViewController jar as dependency in viewcontroller project of the new application. 
I tried running it but it throws -

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException][oracle.adf.model.bc4j.DCJboDataControl.findVariable]
```

Any ideas how I can  run this

Comment: Are they plain JAR files or ADF Library JAR files?

Comment: They are ADF Lib jar

Answer (score 0):

IN Jdeveloper you have the option of creating new workspace from EAR file:

```
New Galery -> Applications -> Application From EAR file.
```

Myself, I had some success using this feature on small ADF applications.

Comment: I have only Jars not the whole ear

Comment: There is a small chance of decompiling the jars... You may be able to retrieve all XML's, but you need to use JAD to decompile .class. Anyway, you will need to reconstruct file by file, presuming you know and understand every file an ADF application creates.

Answer (score 0):

Something doesn't make sense - a viewController project is not packaged as a JAR it will be a WAR file.
Which files are in the JAR file for the viewController project? do you have the web.xml file? the databindings.cpx file?

Answer (score 0):

I tube too many headaches over this.

But here's the solution.

1. Modify the deployment of Model and create a new deploy with
   "ADF Library Jar File" (Important)
2. Add the library in the controller and ready View

Here are the steps in more detail

http://gopsatora.blogspot.com/2011/04/adding-adf-library-jar-to-project.html